# Enviar y tomar respuesta XML a través de TCP

Tags: c#, xml

Hola yo quiero enviar un XML a traves de un mensaje TCP en c#.

Necesito saber como crear el XML en el formato que les dejo, como enviarlo a un host y port y después tomar la respuesta XML que me devuelva el host.

Les dejo un ejemplo del formato del XML.

```
POST xml.xml HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Length: 280

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<NODO1>
    <PARAM1>VALOR1</PARAM1>
    <PARAM2>VALOR2</PARAM2>
    <PARAM3>VALOR3</PARAM3>
    <PARAM4>VALOR4</PARAM4>
    <PARAM5>VALOR5</PARAM5>
    <PARAM6>VALOR6</PARAM6>
    <PARAM7>VALOR7</PARAM7> 
    <PARAM8>VALOR8</PARAM8>
</NODO1>
```

Desde ya gracias.

Solución al error:

```
                        writer.AutoFlush = false;
                        writer.Write("POST xml.xml HTTP/1.1");
                        writer.Write("\r\n");
                        writer.Write("Content-Type: application/xml");
                        writer.Write("\r\n");
                        writer.Write("Content-Length: ");
                        writer.Write(encoding.GetBytes(message).Length);
                        writer.Write("\r\n");
                        writer.Write("\r\n");
                        writer.Write(message);
                        writer.Write("\r\n");
                        writer.Write("\r\n");
                        writer.Flush();

                        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, encoding);
                        while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
                        {
                            response += reader.ReadLine();
                        }
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

espero este código te ayude.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{

    // NOTE: Generated code may require at least .NET Framework 4.5 or .NET Core/Standard 2.0.
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class NODO1
    {

        private string pARAM1Field;

        private string pARAM2Field;

        private string pARAM3Field;

        private string pARAM4Field;

        private string pARAM5Field;

        private string pARAM6Field;

        private string pARAM7Field;

        private string pARAM8Field;

        /// <remarks/>
        public string PARAM1
        {
            get
            {
                return this.pARAM1Field;
            }
            set
            {
                this.pARAM1Field = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string PARAM2
        {
            get
            {
                return this.pARAM2Field;
            }
            set
            {
                this.pARAM2Field = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string PARAM3
        {
            get
            {
                return this.pARAM3Field;
            }
            set
            {
                this.pARAM3Field = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string PARAM4
        {
            get
            {
                return this.pARAM4Field;
            }
            set
            {
                this.pARAM4Field = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string PARAM5
        {
            get
            {
                return this.pARAM5Field;
            }
            set
            {
                this.pARAM5Field = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string PARAM6
        {
            get
            {
                return this.pARAM6Field;
            }
            set
            {
                this.pARAM6Field = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string PARAM7
        {
            get
            {
                return this.pARAM7Field;
            }
            set
            {
                this.pARAM7Field = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string PARAM8
        {
            get
            {
                return this.pARAM8Field;
            }
            set
            {
                this.pARAM8Field = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public static class MyExtension
    {
        public static string SerializeObject<T>(this T toSerialize, Encoding encoding)
        {
            XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings
            {
                Indent = true,
                OmitXmlDeclaration = false,
                Encoding = encoding
            };

            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(toSerialize.GetType());

            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream, xmlWriterSettings))
                {
                    xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, toSerialize);
                }
                return encoding.GetString(stream.ToArray());
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        private static readonly string hostname = "host"; // recuperar de configuración
        private static readonly int port = 1234; // recuperar de configuración
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var nodo = new NODO1()
            {
                PARAM1 = "PARAM1",
                PARAM2 = "PARAM2",
                PARAM3 = "PARAM3",
                PARAM4 = "PARAM4",
                PARAM5 = "PARAM5",
                PARAM6 = "PARAM6",
                PARAM7 = "PARAM7",
                PARAM8 = "PARAM8",
            };
            SendMessage(nodo);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void SendMessage(NODO1 nodo)
        {
            var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");

            var message = nodo.SerializeObject<NODO1>(encoding);

            SendTCP(message, encoding);
        }

        private static void SendTCP(string message, Encoding encoding)
        {
            string response;

            using (var client = new TcpClient(hostname, port))
            {
                using (var stream = client.GetStream())
                {
                    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, encoding)) 
                    {
                        writer.AutoFlush = false;
                        writer.Write(encoding.GetBytes(message).Length);
                        writer.Write(message);
                        writer.Flush();

                        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, encoding);
                        response = reader.ReadLine();

                        writer.Close();
                        stream.Close();
                        client.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Estoy probandolo y tengo un problema al generar el mensaje no esta correcto el formato entonces me devuelve error yo supongo que es por esto <NODO1 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> me aparece por defecto.

Comment: Logre sacar los namespaces pero me sigue devolviendo este error en el response HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error

Comment: Hola. Puedes poner el código de tu envío? Me extraña que te esté dando un error http cuando envias por TCP..

Comment: El error estaba en lo que estaba enviando el texto tenia que esta de manera identica al ejemplo que puse.

mi codigo de SendTCP quedo asi:

writer.AutoFlush = false;
writer.Write("POST xml.xml HTTP/1.1");
writer.Write("\r\n");
writer.Write("Content-Type: application/xml");
writer.Write("\r\n");
writer.Write("Content-Length: ");
writer.Write(encoding.GetBytes(message).Length);
writer.Write("\r\n");
writer.Write(message);
writer.Write("\r\n");
writer.Flush();

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, encoding);
response = reader.ReadLine();

Comment: Ahora tengo un problema al tomar el response 

response = reader.ReadLine();

Al llegar a esta linea no sigue y tampoco sale por try catch se queda esperando respuesta supongo. 

Tampoco puedo debuggiar el reader no me deja ver que hay adentro.

El servidor es externo por ahí no tengo que enviarlo como tcp y tengo que enviarlo como http. Desde su lado me dijeron que era a través de tcp

Comment: Hola. Puedes editar el código en tu pregunta?

Comment: buenas. el error se debia a que me faltaban estas etiquetas y 2 espacios POST xml.xml HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Length: Ya lo solucione muchas gracias es lo que buscaba edito la pregunta para que quede la solucion